Procedural trail follow mesh
I'm trying to make a procedural trail in geo-nodes. But I have no idea how to make trail follow mesh position. Somehow I have to calculate movement direction and set position of points according to that but my math is terrible. Need help. 

try this:
trail with icospheres:

or as curve:

result:


Hi Chris, I tried your suggestion but Instead of points follow my mesh behind, they do the opposite

Okey that worked. My mistake: I was using the same object to make trail and animate. I made two objects one for my animation and one for the trail. Thanks.

you are welcome
